# What's the difference between yarn timeline service & MR2 history server

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

In hadoop2 there's timeline service used for yarn and also the MRV2 history server, so what's the difference between them? What's the main purpose of a stand-alone timeline service?

Answer (score 3):

As Hadoop has shifted from MapReduce to other execution engines (Spark, Tez, Flink) the Job History server which was designed with MapReduce in mind no longer worked. The Job History server also only provides stats on completed jobs and has/had scalability issues. The Application Timeline Server(ATS) addressed these problems and introduced the concept of a `flow` which is a series of jobs being treated as one entity rather than as a set of jobs (MapReduce).

Anyway, that was the original intent.  You can read more in the official docs and the JIRAs have several design documents included.

#### References

- [The YARN Timeline Server](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/TimelineServer.html)
- [The YARN Timeline Service v.2](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/TimelineServiceV2.html)
- [YARN-5355: YARN Timeline Service v.2: alpha 2](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-5355)
- [YARN-2928: YARN Timeline Service v.2: alpha 1](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-2928)
- [YARN-1530: [Umbrella] Store, manage and serve per-framework application-timeline data](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-1530) This includes the original application timeline design proposal.